# Crear un PowerShell que borre ficheros y carpetas mas antiguos a 5 días

Tags: powershell

Quiero crear un PowerShell que borre ficheros y carpetas mas antiguos a 5 días y que genere un log donde queden anotado todos los archivos borrados.

Lo que he conseguido es esto, pero no se me borran las carpetas, solo los ficheros:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\Jhonny\Desktop\Curro"
$NumDays = 0 
$CurDate = get-date
$TestDate = $Curdate.AddDays(-$NumDays)

$strData = "Files deleted from: " + $folder + " on " + $CurDate     

get-childitem $folder -recurse | foreach { 
    If ($_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo") 
    { 
        If ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $TestDate) 
        { 
        $strData = "File to delete: " + $_.Name + " " + $_.LastWriteTime 
        $strData | out-file -Append DeletedFiles.log 
        $_.Delete() 
        $strData | out-file "c:\DeletedFiles.log"
       } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Es probable que los directorios no sean del tipo "FileInfo" y nunca entre en el proceso de borrado. Es una sugerencia no sé muy bien de PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque estás filtrando por el tipo "FileInfo" y el tipo de los directorios es "DirectoryInfo".

Entonces, debería quitar el if que comprueba el tipo, en primer lugar ¿para que está ahí?

Y dejar el resto igual, opcionalmente podrías comprobar el tipo antes de eliminar el archivo/carpeta en caso de que quieras eliminar las carpetas de forma recursiva.

Ejm:

```
$folder = "C:\Users\Jhonny\Desktop\Curro"
$NumDays = 0 
$CurDate = get-date
$TestDate = $Curdate.AddDays(-$NumDays)

$strData = "Files deleted from: " + $folder + " on " + $CurDate     

get-childitem $folder -recurse | foreach { 
    If ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $TestDate) 
    { 
        $strData = "File to delete: " + $_.Name + " " + $_.LastWriteTime 
        $strData | out-file -Append DeletedFiles.log 
        $strData | out-file "c:\DeletedFiles.log"
        If ($_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo") {
            $_.Delete()
        } else {
            $_.Delete($true)
        }
   }
}
```